# How to relink lots of missing image files with changed file extensions?

Tags: materials, linked-data, data-blocks, library

So here is my situation: I have a huge PBR Shader Library and most of the images in there are .png and .tif. I would really like to convert all of these images to jpg to save on disk space (This should save me aproximately 200gb of diskspace). But if i do this blender will lose all of the links to these images because the file extension changed. Is there a way to tell Blender "Hey here are all the missing files, just only look at the file names and ignore the changed extensions"?

I really dont want to do this manually... Thanks in advance for your help!